# How can I add shine on an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Could someone please tell me how to add a small shine to an object, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You could also add it via a lens flare. Through the compositor. I feel it would give you more control as well. See this YouTube tutorial from Blender Diploma.
https://youtu.be/iMjcyL0QvIU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of key factors you must have to even get close to this effect:

1. You need to have a material with some amount of glossy mixed into it.
2. Then you need to bevel the edges of your geometry
3. Add a light to the scene (a strong one if possible).
4. You should be able to get some level of light reflection off the edge in the render.
5. Then in compositing you'll need to pump up the glint with nodes and then run it through a glare node to get something similar to the example.

**Level Up Tip**
If you can get that working, you might want to try Troy S's [new LUT's for blender](https://github.com/sobotka/bassam-test) which allow your scenes to be rendered with high dynamic range. One of the main benefits of high dynamic range is that glints and glares are much more powerful in the compositing phase.

**Screen Shots (using default sRGB LUT)**

1. Material setup, geometry and light

[image]

2. Alternate angle of object in scene

[image]

3. Compositing Setup to accentuate glint and add glare effect

[image]

Comment: Thanks Todd, what light would i use and how would i turn up the glint? Thanks again

Comment: You can see in the screen shot that I'm using a spotlight from the back to get the glint on the front top edge bevel. I cranked the strength up to 5000 to add more reflection. The spotlight is good because it gives you more creative control.